# Microsoft Azure sync database and apps

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

i am kinda new in my work and they asked me to make a research about microsoft Azure.
after few days of research i think this is a good solution for my project but I still have one Question i can't find the answer (not enough experience about it).

To be simple, my project is to make one of our database in the cloud (which is synchronize with our local MS SQL database).

I would like to create an apps (interface) who allow user to change the Azure database (internet), i want this database to be sync with our local database.

For example, for a test. I will have my computer or tablet, accessing to the Azure apps online to change the database, but IF the internet goes off, i would like to be able to still use this apps offline to modify my local database, which will be re-synchronize with Azure database when my internet comes back.

The question is, is it possible to make an apps on Microsoft Azure which will works even online/offline, Just in case the internet goes done during the modification, the apps will change the local database instead of the online one?

Thank you for your help!
I hope i was cleared.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Synchronize Remote Server DB with Local DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354576/how-to-synchronize-remote-server-db-with-local-db)

Comment: You could improve the readability of your question. That would help making it clearer too.